# Label control Text is not HTML Encoded

Tags: web-part

I have a simple Webpart which has label control displaying some text, but I don't know why Label control's text is not rendered as html encoded.
I have worked with ASP.NET site development and it encodes in it.

> So my questions that why it is left not to encode in SharePoint but
>   Asp.Net sites.

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    Label myLable = new Label();
    myLable = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to insert the text encoded into the HTML then it's better to use a Literal control and set the [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode%28v=vs.90%29):

```
protected override void CreateChildControls() 
{ 
    var myLiteral = new Literal (); 
    myLiteral.Mode = LiteralMode.Encode;
    myLiteral.Text = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"; 

}
```

The Label controls purpose in ASP.NET isn't to render plain text, but to render text used as a Label for an Associated Control. If you want that text encoded you need to encode it yourselves using [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [SPEncode.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode.htmlencode)

Comment: I want to know why in ASP.NET by default the Text property value always be rendered as encoded but not in SharePoint

Comment: There is no difference, it's the same control. ASP.NET isn't encoding either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends highly in what context it gets rendered. Try however the use method of the SPEncore, such as HtlmEncode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode.htmlencode

Comment: I have updated my question, please check

Comment: That is all that your web part is doing? Could you please drop more details,e.g. in what control are you dropping this Label?